# Why am i unable to run urllib in python

Tags: python, urllib

This is the code that seems to be correct:

```
import urllib.error, urllib.request, urllib.parse
import json

target='http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?'
local=input('Enter loction: ')
url=target+urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':local,'key':42})
print('retreiving',url)
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
print('retreived',len(data),'character')
js=json.loads(data)
print(json.dumps(js,indent=4))
print('Place id',js['results'][0]['place id'])
```

Error:

```
Enter file name: South Federal University
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\this pc\Desktop\Course\dude.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.error, urllib.request, urllib.parse
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email
  File "c:\Users\this pc\Desktop\Course\email.py", line 4, in <module>
    fh = open(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'South Federal University'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As evident from `c:\Users\this pc\Desktop\Course\email.py` appearing in the traceback, you have a file named `email.py` in the same directory as your script, and Python's import machinery makes it think it needs to import that (via [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/581c4434de62d9d36392f10e65866c081fb18d71/Lib/urllib/request.py#L86) in `urllib.request`).

Rename that `email.py` to e.g. `email_test.py` or whatnot - in any case, a name that's not a Python standard module - and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks a lot I was stuck on this since 2 days, then I finally opened StackOverflow for the first time for help.